# PHP: Data loss when pass an object

Tags: php, arrays, sockets, object, reference

I have a Class A with an array of Socket

```
Class A
{
    public $Clients = array();
}
```

and a Class B which extends Thread to which in the constructor I pass Class A .

```
Class B extends Thread
{
    private $a;
    public function __construct($A)
    {
        $this->a = $A;
    }
}
```

Next, If I add `print_r` instruction,

```
$this->a = $A;
print_r($this->a);
print_r($A);
```

I have this output for `$this->a`

```
A Object
(
    [Clients] => Array
    (
        [0]=> 0
    )
)
```

this output for `$A`.

```
A Object
(
    [Clients] => Array
    (
        [0]=> Resource id #N
    )
)
```

Why do I lose socket data?

I have tried to pass `&$A` in construct.

Comment: Could use var_dump instead of print_r? Var_dump shows object id.

Comment: Using var_dump I have:
object(PHPWebSocket)#1
and
object(PHPWebSocket)#3
They are different, but should be equal, or no?

Comment: Yes, the same object uses the same id. Search for cloning or accident assignment.

Comment: But I want to know why...I need the same object

Comment: We need code to reproduce behaviour.